# Why did Athaliah destroy all those of royal descent in 2 Kings 11:1?

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of

Melachim II 11:1

***"And Athaliah, Ahaziah's mother, saw that her son was dead, and she rose and destroyed all those of royal descent."***

What was her reason for killing those of royal stock?

Comment: What’s wrong with v. 3, which says she claimed the throne for herself afterwards?

Comment: In Jean Racine's version, the motive is that Jehu had just killed all of Athaliah's family (Ahab was her father), so now she did the same to David's line in revenge (I'm leaving this as a comment since it's not a Jewish source)

Comment: Building on DonielF's comment--as per several examples, when an illegitimate(Herod) or insecure(Solomon, Joram)ruler comes to power, they try to stay in power by eliminating either the legitimate ruling line or the possible competition from within their own family.